# Inject ToMethod() with additional property?

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm injecting a RestSharp `IRestClient` instance to make API calls like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IRestClient>()
      .ToMethod(context => new RestClient("http://localhost:63146/api/"));
```

However, I also need to authenticate using a `HttpBasicAuthenticator`. I am currently injecting this `IAuthenticator` like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticator>()
      .ToMethod(context => new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password"));
```

Is there a way to combine the two so that I only need to inject the `IRestClient` and the authenticator is attached by default?

For instance, I tried something like:

```
kernel.Bind<IRestClient>()
      .ToMethod(context => 
          new RestClient("http://localhost:63146/api/")
               .Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password"));
```

But that's not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToMehtod` takes a regular `Func<IContext, T>` where you are not restricted to simple object creation but you can write any specify complex function.

So you can easily combine the two call with:

```
kernel.Bind<IRestClient>()
    .ToMethod(context => {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:63146/api/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");
        return client;
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I need to better understand `Funcs` so that I can figure this out myself next time.